Calculation of spin-seebeck coefficient
I have been working with the calculation of transport properties of ferromagnets using the BoltzTraP2 package. I have managed to compute Seebeck coefficient, electrical conductivity, and power factor as a function of temperature for my crystal lattice, however i wanted to plot these quantities in both spin-up and spin-down channel. Similar to figure 4 in this paper (DOI:10.1080/14786435.2019.1587184) As seen, in Figure4, there are multiple dual axis plots, on each axis is a spin channel. I wanted to calculate these spin-dependent seebeck coefficients for my lattice as well.
I couldnt find a source about how to do this calculations, how can this be done?
